# How can "running down the plane" be interpreted in this SOAD song?

Tags: popular-refrains

In the lyrics of a System Of A Down song called [Roulette](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ByBhN_X5nVg) the following part can be found:

> Left a message, but it ain't a bit of use 
>   I have some pictures, the wild might be the deuce 
>   Today you saw, you saw me, you explained 
>   Playing the show and running down the plane

To have some context: the song itself seems to be about a complicated relationship and some messed up feelings.

I get what he is trying to say with the first three sentences...
But what does the last one sentence mean? Especially *running down the plane*?

Comment: See something like https://www.lyricinterpretations.com/system-of-a-down/roulette. Lyrics aren't subject to normal English usage rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plane is taking off down the runway and you're chasing after it. Instead of having a personal goodbye in the airport, you chose to play your show. This leaves you with feelings of regret and loss as you chase hopelessly after the aircraft as it is headed down the runway as it takes off.